# how to implement randomized hough transform to detect line?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am able to use "cv2.HoughLines" of Opencv to detect lines in an image. But i want to know how can I implement Randomized Hough Transform to detect lines using opencv python as the literature review says RHT performs better than HT. Can anyone please help me?

this is the image i have [image]

after using the following code

```
lines = cv2.HoughLines(imgray, 1, np.pi / 180, 300)
for rho, theta in lines[0]:
 a = np.cos(theta)
 b = np.sin(theta)
 x0 = a * rho
 y0 = b * rho
 x1 = int(x0 + 1000 * (-b))
 y1 = int(y0 + 1000 * (a))
 x2 = int(x0 - 1000 * (-b))
 y2 = int(y0 - 1000 * (a))

cv2.line(imgray, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

i got the following result
[image]

Comment: teaching you how to implement such a complex algorithm is way beyond the scope of this community. that's something you have to learn yourself. I'm sure you'll find some source code and papers online. you may ask for help on small steps on your way but no one will write 200 pages here.

Comment: how can i get multiple lines detected not just one?

Comment: you most likely detect more than one line but at least as formatted as in your post your code will only draw one line as the call to cv2.line is outside t he for loop...

Answer (score 0):

Use the probabalistic Hough transform instead.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html

Comment: probabalistic hough transform is different from RHT.

Comment: @annie that's why I wrote 'instead'. It performs better and you don't have to implement anything. at least the RHT is a probabalistic HT, maybe that's not true the other way around. it's faster. I have never seen a benchmark between both, maybe you can create one ?`:)